# Warning of slow pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt

Tags: meteor

Building a Meteor app I get the message about pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt is three times slower than the native implementation, suggesting to do `meteor npm install --save bcrypt`.
Which when I do I get the following image. any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread

https://forums.meteor.com/t/npm-bcrypt-and-meteor-npm-bcrypt-madness/28714

I think it's non critical, but definitely annoying

Personally I still have the problem, I'm hoping it magically goes away after an upgrade of something

Comment: Fixed by doing `meteor add npm-bcrypt` instead of `meteor npm install --save bcrypt`

Answer (score 0):

You need the node-gyp and windows-build-tools to build bcrypt on windows, you can read the readme file [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) on how to install and configure node-gyp on windows, after that just run `meteor npm install --save bcrypt` to install the brypt package.